# Rails 7.1, log to STDOUT and log/production.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-7

In a new Rails 7.1.2 app, the following lines can be found in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
  .tap  { |logger| logger.formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new }
  .then { |logger| ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger) }
```

This tells the Rails logger to log to `STDOUT`.

I would like to configure it so that it ALSO logs to `log/production.log`, but I can't for the life of me figure it out...

[In this article by Fly.io](https://fly.io/blog/redundant-logs/) it says to add these lines:

```
logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
volume_logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new("/logs/production.log", 3)
logger = logger.extend ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(volume_logger)
```

But it seems like these instructions are for Rails < 7.1, since I get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method` broadcast' for ActiveSupport::Logger:Class`.

How can I do this in Rails 7.1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rails `v7.1` [added](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1fbd812c47f7ba840390942e56d9b2ebbc260901) new `BroadcastLogger` class to handle broadcasting:

```rb
stdout_logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
stdout_logger.formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

file_logger             = ActiveSupport::Logger.new("log/production.log")
file_logger.formatter   = ::Logger::Formatter.new

tagged_stdout_logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(stdout_logger)
tagged_file_logger      = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(file_logger)

broadcast_logger = ActiveSupport::BroadcastLogger.new(tagged_stdout_logger, tagged_file_logger)
config.logger    = broadcast_logger
```

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BroadcastLogger.html*

*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#rails-logger-now-returns-an-activesupport-broadcastlogger-instance*

---

Since `rails v7.1` you could pass `formatter` to `new`, which makes the setup much cleaner: *https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3b012a52540f7e4564d70f1955785bde32269a3d*:

```rb
config.logger = ActiveSupport::BroadcastLogger.new(
  ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new($stdout,              formatter: Logger::Formatter.new)),
  ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new("log/production.log", formatter: Logger::Formatter.new))
)
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the explanation and links, Alex!
This is the condensed version I ended up with:

# config/environments/production.rb
config.logger = [STDOUT, "log/production.log"].map do |destination|
  ActiveSupport::Logger.new(destination)
    .tap  { _1.formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new }
    .then { ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new _1 }
end.then { ActiveSupport::BroadcastLogger.new(*_1) }

(pff, no Markdown or line breaks in comments??)

Comment: In Rails 7.1.1, there seems to be a problem with multiple loggers: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/49745 If you get "no implicit conversion of String into Integer", wait for Rails 7.1.2

Comment: FYI, I am still getting the "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" issue here with Rails 7.1.3