rails deployment production incomplete
capistrano 3.19.1
rails 7.1.3
An application was deployed in two environments to different VPS.
The development deployment went off without a hitch.
But the production environment has two quirks:
• the first is a 'something went wrong' error... however, the bigger issue is
• there is no production.log to be found
Given a response is obtained, it appears nginx is routing the call correctly & passenger is not complaining either.
the deploy/[environment].rb files  direct to the proper directories and all files appear to be in place.
Even touch production.log within th elog directory, then touch tmp/restart.txt from the current directory does not result in any writing to the log file.  Permission stand at -rw-rw-rw- for the created production.log.
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c

> Rails.logger
=>
#<ActiveSupport::BroadcastLogger:0x00007f1c625c0a78
 @broadcasts=
  [#<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x00007f1c625e73f8
    @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00007f1c625cb9f0 @datetime_format=nil>,
    @formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00007f1c625c9a38 @datetime_format=nil>,
    @level=1,
    @level_override={},
    @logdev=
     #<Logger::LogDevice:0x00007f1c625e80c8
      @binmode=false,
      @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>,
      @filename=nil,
      @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x00007f1c625cb928>,
      @mon_data_owner_object_id=4960,
      @shift_age=nil,
      @shift_period_suffix=nil,
      @shift_size=nil>,
    @progname=nil>],
 @formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00007f1c625c9a38 @datetime_format=nil>,
 @progname="Broadcast">

Not having any logs puts one at a loss for debugging...
what should be explored?
Update
The logging was being registered in nginx logs /var/log/nginx.error.log which revealed the 'something went wrong' problem.
ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.
this required a
 RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile  to overcome the error.
Still, the compilation of assets should occur and the logging should not be registered in gninx's error log.
The conundrum remains whole: a single deploy.rb file but different behaviours between development and production (requiring a re-titling of the question) ...

Development typically runs without precompiled assets, while production does - the configurations are different. Hence , running asset:precompile is a common deployment step for prod. The logging issue - hard to tell without more info

'a common deployment step for prod'. yes, but I was under the impression that capistrano has the logic to precompile.  Or is it because on the first deploy it has not manifest against which to compare (which would be odd) ?  I also don't believe I've encountered this behaviour before...

Not familiar with Capistrano’s magic — but clearly in this case at least it was not done

capistrano should fails if any of the steps fail like assets precompilation which is done by require 'capistrano/rails/assets'. also, you're logging to stdout, not production.log, you should probably figure out where your production logs are stored https://stackoverflow.com/a/78092525/207090
